# Adding control inside Datagridview but not in grid

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, controls

I need to add a custom scrollbar (already developped) INSIDE a datagridview, to effectively replace the default one. I insist on the inside because the border of the datagridview must include the scrollbar.
I don't want to rely on a user control, Where I would have to expose all the datagridview property. Currently, the scrollbar works perfectly, but I must put it outside of the datagridview.

I have tried to simply add the scrollbar directly, and dock it, and bring it to front.

```
Datagridview1.Controls.Add(myCustomScrollBar)
myCustomScrollBar.dock =  DockStyle.Right
myCustomScrollBar.visible = true
myCustomScrollBar.bringToFront()
```

That works ! The ScrollBar shows. But it covers a part of the grid. So I need to tell the datagridview that the end of the grid is just before the scrollbar. Maybe by modify the clientrectangle ? or something with regions (Which I don't fully understand) ? Is there a way to achieve what I want ? I considered using paddings or margins, but the first "is not relevant for this control), and for the second, it moves the scrollbar with it, so it's still above the grid.

Comment: I wonder what difference it would make if you put the `DataGridView` it inside a `Panel`, set it's `Dock = Fill` and the `ScrollBar` dock to `Left` and use `Bring To Front`/`Back` commands to arrange the relation of `DataGridView` and `Panel`. Should give you what you want I guess, but I've never ran into this exact scenario.

Comment: I created an empty class that inherits from `VScrollBar`, used your code, and [it worked just fine](https://i.imgur.com/7Ma9s1q.png).

Comment: I missed the bringtofront... So It works.... BUT, it appears above the grid. How Can I tell the datagridview ot use a sort of padding so that the new scrollbar is next to the grid, but inside the borders ?

Comment: And for Oak : I already have datagridview everywhere in my application, and I  would not like to change the layout everywhere. And also, I would like to have a unique control, not two (or three).

Comment: I have edited the question with new informations.

Comment: Build a UserControl.

Comment: I think your method is enough, but may be you can force the original vertical schroll bar always show, and the myCustomScrollBar must be always in front

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use this:

```
    myCustomScrollBar.Top = DataGridView1.Top
    myCustomScrollBar.Left = DataGridView1.Left + DataGridView1.Width
    myCustomScrollBar.Height = DataGridView1.Height
```